# Is there a way to use Google smart home actions while restricting certain users to unlock/lock a specific smart lock door?

Tags: authentication, actions-on-google, google-smartlockpasswords

I'm currently working on a smart lock project. And we want to let our backend server send commands to the relating smart lock. And we are considering Google smart home actions to send some sort of command to the smart lock from our backend server to open/close the lock. But I want to ONLY let the backend server send these commands to the smart locks, and NOT everybody who is connected to the wifi network (as most of the times everybody on the network can control all smart home devices e.g. set volume of speaker, open front door, dim lights etc. etc.). I have seen some things about account linking inside, but not sure if that's what I need. So my question was: Is there a way using smart home actions to only give one person (or in this case entity) access to do certain actions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [two-factor authentication](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/two-factor-authentication) to require a person to give an ack or PIN to send the final command.

The specific architecture of the lock and its connection is up to you, but I don't believe there is a way to limit control of the lock to specific accounts. If there is a Google Home, any individual in the home is able to issue the initial command. If this individual knows the PIN, they can say that as well.